# 301 redirect only the contents of a subfolder and not the subfolder itself

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to work out how to 301 redirect /hall-of-fame/(something-here) only (to /profile/(something-here)), and not redirect if somebody lands on the actual /hall-of-fame/ path.

So far I have:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/hall-of-fame/(.*)$ /profile/$1
```

However this also matches /hall-of-fame/ and redirects that to /profile/ - which I do not want.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not that familiar with .htaccess regex, but have you tried ^/hall-of-fame/(.{1,})$? https://regex101.com/r/uF8aZ8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your regex just a little bit. If you use `(.*)` that means 0 of more characters, so it will also match an empty URI. You need to change it to `(.+)` meaning 1 or more. So there will have to be something after /hall-of-fame before it will redirect.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/hall-of-fame/(.+)$ /profile/$1
```